# Strace shows that the time spent in syscalls is much longer than the total time elapsed. Why?

Tags: system-calls, strace, profiling

I am running an AI inference program based on Tensorflow-gpu.

By running `/usr/bin/strace -c -f /usr/bin/time ./program`, I got the following output:

```
<my program's output>
367.91user 1032.14system 26:43.41elapsed 87%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4158812maxresident)k <----OUTPUT OF TIME
1760inputs+24outputs (0major+4259846minor)pagefaults 0swaps
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall                              <----OUTPUT OF STRACE
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 88.45 34105.209840        7166   4759375    217371 futex
  8.71 3356.854321       49032     68462           poll
  2.68 1032.625515     2044803       505           wait4
  0.05   21.006854         119    177269           clock_gettime
<..and some other syscalls that didn't took very long...>
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00 38559.038652               5385548    247845 total
```

It shows that my program spent `34105` seconds in `futex` alone, which is **20 times longer** than the elapsed time of `26:43.41`.

I assumed that `strace` was recording the total system call time on all of my cores, so I re-experimented with only a single core enabled (using `taskset`), but the problem persisted.

**Edit:**

I did use taskset with the `--all-tasks` option:

```
/usr/bin/taskset --all-tasks --cpu-list 0 /usr/bin/strace  -c -f /usr/bin/time ./program
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include details on how you used `taskset` to constrain where your process and its threads/children executed?  For example, did you use the `--all-tasks` option?

Comment: @AndyDalton Yes I did. I have edited my question.

Comment: I think the issue is that's a blocking call, so you can have multiple threads "in" that system call at the same time, even when everything is pinned to a single CPU.

Comment: @AndyDalton That was one of my assumptions, but a little experiment I did proved it wrong.

I wrote a simple program where it starts 10 `pthread`s that all try to grab a `pthread_mutex_t`. Only the first thread to grab the lock will `usleep` for 10 seconds in the critical section, causing the other 9 threads to block in `futex`. 

I ran it with `taskset`, `strace` and `time`, and `strace` reported that the system calls (especially `futex`) only took 0.06 seconds in total, when `time` reported 10 seconds elapsed. If your assumption were correct, `futex` should be 90 seconds, right?

Comment: I did a similar experiment, and got the same results as you did.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @AndyDalton I managed to reproduce this phenomenon with a simple program. It is basically a program that starts up 5 threads, each making 100000 system calls to `FUTEX_WAKE` on a futex that nobody is wating on. The `futex` time will exceed the wall time only if I start up multiple threads doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `man strace` I see:

> ```
> -c
> --summary-only
>        ...
>        If -c is used with -f, only aggregate totals  for  all  traced
>        processes are kept.
>
> -f
> --follow-forks
>        Trace child processes as  they  are  created  by  currently
>        traced  processes  as a result of the fork(2), vfork(2) and
>        clone(2) system calls.
>        ...
> ```

Here, you're specifying both `-c` and `-f`.  If your process forks or is multi-threaded, then the results are aggregated across the processes.  If, for example, you had multiple threads all blocked in `futex()`, you could see the behavior that you're seeing.

The `futex` system call that you observe unusually long times in is a blocking call, so it doesn't actively take CPU time -- you can have multiple threads blocked that call at the same time, even if they're all pinned to the same CPU.